# Testing error - Create component fails out of the box

Tags: angular, angular-test

I am new to testing in angular and having some difficulty. When a new component or service is created, a new testing file is created as shown below (for a component). However, running ng test fails the simple 'should create' test and says that the 'component' variable is empty.

What am I missing? Do I need to inject the same dependencies for the component?

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { CreatorStudioComponent } from './creator-studio.component';

describe('CreatorStudioComponent', () => {
  let component: CreatorStudioComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreatorStudioComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CreatorStudioComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreatorStudioComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Most likely, the `TestBed` is missing declarations and imports needed for your `CreatorStudioComponent`. See this section of Angular's testing docs for ways to handle this: https://angular.io/guide/testing#setup-with-module-imports

Comment: Thanks. I tried reading through the docs, but I can't understand a lot of it. Are we supposed to make fake services to test with our components? If so, doesn't that just introduce the possibility that errors exist solely in the mock service? Don't we have to then change the test each time we change the service?

Comment: Also, multiple methods of placing a mock service into the component seem to be given. Why? Why not have a preferred and documented method?

There also seem to be instances where the displayed code differs from what the text seems to be indicating.

Comment: This largely varies depending on your setup, but here's a general explanation. If you take a look at the module (maybe `app.module.ts`) where you've declared the `CreatorStudioComponent`, you have imported other modules (for example, UI component modules from Angular Material). You need to import those modules that the `CreatorStudioComponent` depends on when configuring the TestBed. You don't need to mock all services, but for example, if you have a service that makes API calls, it's best to have them return mock data.